# Where are the private members of an anonymous immediate function stored?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log, private-methods

Take for example:

```
var myobj; // this will be the object


(function () {
    // private members
    var name = "my, oh my";


    // implement the public part
    // note -- no `var`
    myobj = {
        // privileged method
        getName: function () {
            return name;
        }
    };
}());


myobj.getName(); // "my, oh my”
```

from the JavaScript Patterns book by Stefanov.

If you were to use the Chrome console, how would you locate the variable name, **without the** privileged method?

Take for example this code:

```
var a_1 = function(){console.log(this)}

a_1();
```

The window object that it logs, you can browse to a_1 - see the image attached (link below)

[console logging the window object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ugSA.png)

Could we do the same with **name** variable in the anonymous immediate function?

Let me know if I have constructed my question clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're asking if the variable can be read in the console in Chrome.

The answer is ***yes***. Type `window.myobj` into the console and expand the objects as shown below, and you'll see `"my, oh my"` under `name`.

> ```
> window.myobj -> getName -> <function scope> -> Closure -> name;
> ```

---

If this was more than just a curiosity, and you were hoping for security via closure variables, you won't get it. There's *no* security in JavaScript.

Comment: Yep! that's what I was looking for. Question was based on curiosity/learning interest. Thanks @cookie !